# UIAlertViewController when presenting shows strange warning

Tags: ios, xcode7.2

all of a sudden I am getting this warning when " [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; "

**the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-03-18 20:34:00.315 TestTableView[15391:1275189] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2016-03-18 20:34:00.316 TestTableView[15391:1275189] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbff9e39fb0>, and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbff9e39fb0>.
2016-03-18 20:34:00.317 TestTableView[15391:1275189] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
**

I also tried --> [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

Any ideas how to decipher this ?

JZ

Comment: If the alert view works correctly, I'd suggest filing a bug with Apple and ignoring the warning for now.

Comment: Great Matt , thanks much. Will do ..